# What is difference between @PreAuthorize and @security annotation in Spring?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

What is difference between `@PreAuthorize` and `@Security` annotations in Spring?

And what does it mean passing a parameter like `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER_ROLE')")`?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean `@Secured` instead of `@Security`, because I haven't heard of the latter.

`@PreAuthorize` simply specifies which role(s) a, currently logged in, user must have to execute a method.

`@Secured` does pretty much the same afair, but it's hardly ever used, because `@PreAuthorize` enables specifications that include `AND`.

For example, `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('DB_ADMIN') AND hasRole('ADMIN')")` is not possible with `@Secured`.